# How do I define multiple variables within a switch by random?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm a noob in Java and need some help with this. I wonder how to get a random name for each of the `nameOne`, `nameTwo` and `NameThree` strings without duplicating the whole `switch` statement. Can someone please give me an advice on how to do this without bloating up my code? My actual name list is very long.

```
public class multipleNamesPicker {public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nameOne = null;
    String nameTwo = null;
    String nameThree = null;
    char gender1 = 'a'; 
    char gender2 = 'a';
    char gender3 = 'a';

    byte randomNumber1 = (byte)(Math.random()*2+1);
    switch(randomNumber1) {
      case 1: gender1 = 'w';
      case 2: gender1 = 'm';
    }

    byte randomNumber2 = (byte)(Math.random()*5+1);
    if(gender1 == 'w'){
        switch(randomNumber2) {
           case 1: nameOne = "Edna";
           case 2: nameOne = "Martha";
           case 3: nameOne = "Berta";
           case 4: nameOne = "Margaret";
           case 5: nameOne = "Anna";
        }
     }

     else{
        switch(randomNumber2) {
          case 1: nameOne = "Peter";
          case 2: nameOne = "Paul";
          case 3: nameOne = "Pablo";
          case 4: nameOne = "Henry";
          case 5: nameOne = "George";
        }
     }

    System.out.println(nameOne + ", " + nameTwo + " and " + nameThree);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to put them in two `Array`'s (One for female names and one for male names) and then have something like

```
if(gender1 == 'w'){
    nameOne = femaleNames[randomNum];
}
```

Where `femaleNames` is your `Array` of female names and `randomNum` is your random number. Just make sure `randomNum` is within bounds of your `Array`

Comment: Hi GBlodgett, I'm not sure if you got my thank you from a few days ago. This solved my problem. Thank you very much! :)